# "type 'TimeSpanPicker' was not found" when using the Coding4Fun Toolkit

Tags: windows-phone-7, toolkit

I'm trying to use the TimSpanPicker from the Coding4Fun Toolkit for Windows Phone. I added the references to

> Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls
>
> Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.Toolkit
>
> Coding4Fun.Phone.Site.Controls

and the namespaces

```
xmlns:coding4fun="clr-namespace:Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls;assembly=Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls"
xmlns:c4ftoolkit="clr-namespace:Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.Toolkit;assembly=Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

But when I try to insert the `TimeSpanPicker-Control` I get following error when loading the page:

```
$exception  {"The type 'TimeSpanPicker' was not found. [Line: 52 Position: 18]"}    System.Exception {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException}
```

The XAML looks like that:

```
<c4ftoolkit:TimeSpanPicker></c4ftoolkit:TimeSpanPicker>
```

I don't get any indication in VS that someting might be missing. Any idea where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding/declaring the "TimeSpanPicker" from the code-behind to see if VisualStudio gives you more hints.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to header as a reference :

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.Toolkit;assembly=Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Hope this will work!

Cheers!